# How to replicate a single column of data from one excel spreadsheet to another based on the contents of a cell

Tags: excel, calculated-columns

I have an array in a worksheet (S1) with approximately 100 columns and over 7500 rows. Cells in the first row of S1 (A1, B1, ...) have header identifiers. Column A contains timestamps applicable to the data in the row they're in.

Data are periodically added to S1 typically by inserting a new timestamp in S1!A2 and newly sampled data in the rest of row 2 thus increasing the number of rows by one each update.

In another worksheet (S2) I have:

```
S2!A2=AVERAGE(B:B)
S2!A3=STDEV.S(B:B)
S2!C1='Z-SCORE'
S2!Ci=(Bi-$A$2) * $A$3
```

for each i >= 2. Finally, S2!A1 contains text entered by a user. For example, 'P_ID1'

I need a formula that looks up the cell in S1 row 1 that contains the content of S2!A1 and replicates the column in which the heading is found into S2!B:B. It should handle dynamic changes and should not contain 0 values from empty cells in S1. In other words, it should return a dynamic array. Here is an example that does not work.

```
S2!B1=S1!B:B
```

This is a dynamic array, but it fills in more than 900,000 cells mostly with the value 0 which causes the average and standard deviation formulas to fail. It also does not search for the correct column to duplicate. A better example is

```
S2!B1=FILTER(S1!B:B, ISNUMBER(S1!B:B) + ISTEXT(S1!B:B))
```

In this example, S2!B:B is populated with the right data and is dynamic. However, it also does not depend on S2!A1 which is required.

A third (failing) example:

```
S2!B1=HLOOKUP(S2!$A$1, S1!$A$1:$??, 1)
S2!B2=HLOOKUP(S2!$A$1, S1!$A$1:$??, 2)
...
```

These formulas correctly return the right column, but fails in the obvious way. The value that replaces ?? must be already known which makes the resulting column not dynamic and depends on both the number of columns and rows in S1. Also, it is computationally intensive and somewhat difficult to construct.

The array in S1 could be transposed, but I'm not sure that VLOOKUP would be much better than HLOOKUP and charting the data would still be difficult as well.

It is possible, but not realistic to create a worksheet for each label (about 100 of them), to replicate all the arithmetic across those worksheets and render the data with about 100 charts. I would like to find a way to have a cell in one worksheet (S2) as described above into which the user enters the header name of the column for which analysis is desired and then to have the correct column duplicated in S2. This also greatly simplifies charting.

I looked at XLOOKUP, INDEX, ADDRESS, CHOOSE, MATCH, FILTER, SORT and many other methods and haven't found an answer.

Comment: Not sure what your are asking **I would like to find a way to have a cell in one new worksheet into which the user enters the header name of the column for which analysis is desired and then to have formulas that replicate the relevant column from the 100x7000+ array into a 1x7000+ column in the new worksheet.** You want interaction on your sheet either this means setting up the sheet with formulas that do the calcs and create the charts. Creating the Sheet is something Openpyxl can do/help with but also appears you want/need help with Excel formulas to obtain/create the data calcs,

Comment: Remember Openpyxl is static, it add/changes values/formulas, using Openpyxl does not stop VBA being used in the sheet, ***nothing happens on the sheet as far as calculations go until you open that workbook in Excel so VBA can run at that time***, but Openpyxl cannot be used for VBA coding. Either way the question seems too vague as to what help you are requesting.

Comment: Thank you, @moken for your feedback. I've inserted some example formulas, removed the unnecessary references to openpyxl and tried to more exactly explain the problem.

Comment: If you are having problems getting an Excel formula to do what you require maybe Xlwings UDFs would work. Firstly this would require that you are running Excel in a Windows environment. If not then it's not going help. If so then you can use Xlwings  in python to write code to do what you need (copy values from on sheet to another with what validation needed) then call the python code as a VBA macro. So if you set a macro that activates on `S2!A1` changing the macro can then call the Xlwings code to update the sheet as required.

Comment: Thanks again, @moken. I'm using macos so I assume Xlwings is not available. I experimented until I found an answer that does not depend on python or VBA. There are still problems, but it works.

Comment: Xlwings will work with MACOS, but for some things including UDFs it's not usable. It's a pity as it may have helped address some of the short falls you're finding with the Excel formulas. I don't work with Excel formulas too much myself  when it gets complex so not a lot of help in that area, mainly use other languages to interact with and use Excel for displays instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One answer I found by experimentation (which looks inefficient, but it works) is below. The essential trick is to use ADDRESS and INDIRECT to construct the dynamic array. (For brevity if not clarity I removed the sheetname S2 in formulas in S2.)

In my original post I had:

```
A2=AVERAGE(B:B)
A3=STDEV.S(B:B)
C1='Z-SCORE'
Ci=(Bi-$A$2) * $A$3
```

For clarity in the answer I add helper cells and move the locations of the calculation of the mean and standard deviations. The complete answer including the calculation of mean, standard deviation and zscores involves formulas in worksheet S2 and is shown below:

```
A2=IF(ISBLANK($A$1), "Enter name of required data above", MATCH($A$1,S1!1:1,0))
A3=IF(ISBLANK($A$1), "", SUBSTITUTE(ADDRESS(1,$A$2,4),"1",""))
A4=IF(ISBLANK($A$1), "", "S1!" & $A$3 & ":" & $A$3)
A5=IF(ISBLANK($A$1), "", AVERAGE(B:B))
A6=IF(ISBLANK($A$1), "", STDEV.S(B:B))

B1=IF(ISBLANK($A$1), "", FILTER(INDIRECT($A$4), ISNUMBER(INDIRECT($A$4) + ISTEXT(INDIRECT($A$4))

C1="Z_SCORE"
Ci=IF(ISBLANK($A$1), "", ($Bi-$A$5) / $A$6)
```

I would still very much appreciate a more efficient answer.